# Launchy launches an old version of Firefox instead of the latest version I have installed

Tags: windows

I cannot seem to be launch Firefox with launchy. It always brings up FF3.1 instead of the latest version I have installed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably got a shortcut somewhere in the list of locations that Launchy indexes to an old installation of Firefox - which Launchy deems are more relevant than the shortcut to the latest version (I think it determines relevance based on the number of times you've launched a particular shortcut, hence an old shortcut is likely to get priority). Remove the old shortcut, re-index Launchy (right-click Launchy box and hit "Rebuild Catalog"), and you should be set.